# How do I integrate Jersey with Tomcat using Maven

Tags: rest, tomcat, maven, jersey

I'm trying to use Jersey to create REST services using tomcat as a container. I'm struggling to figure out what the maven artifacts are.

I'd like to use the jersey servlet to serve manage my service.

```xml
<dependencies>

    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>         
    </dependency>       

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-repos</id>
        <name>Glassfish Repos</name>
        <url> http://maven.java.net</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Just getting invalid checksum errors, etc...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ref: jersey user-guide, [Chapter 11. Dependencies](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#chapter_deps)

artifactId should be 'jersey-server', not 'jersey-project'.

the following dependency is ok to me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

The following dependencies work for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am using Tomcat as a servlet container for Jersey.

Answer (score 2):

For tomcat, add below line into your pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                      <warName>test-ws</warName> 
                    <dependentWarExcludes></dependentWarExcludes>
                    <webappDirectory>
                        ${env.CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/test-ws
                         </webappDirectory> 

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

"I'd like to use the jersey servlet to serve manage my service."

For Jersey Servlet add this line into your pom.xml

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-ea</version>
        </dependency>
```

For more jersey dependency add below givens are into your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-ea</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-ea</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-ea</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-ea</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletcontainer/) mkyong troubleshooting helpful.

In my case I just added:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
```

to the **pom.xml** and selected **"Build with dependencies"** (i.e.: `mvn install`) in Netbeans.